# LEFT JOIN and COUNT

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have three tables like so:
1. cosmetics with cosm_id as primary key, AI, cosm_name is unique.

```
| cosm_id | cosm_brand | cosm_name | cosm_volume
```

2. cosmInOut with cosmInOut_id as Primary key, AI, Foreign key as name cosmInOut_qtyIn is always 1

```
| cosmInOut_id | cosmInOut_name | cosmInOut_qtyIn | cosmInOut_4sale
```

3. cosmSpent with cosmSpent_id as Primary key, AI, Foreign key as name. cosmSpent_volume is a fraction of cosm_volume

```
 | cosmSpent_id | cosmSpent_name | cosmSpent_volume
```

What I want is to create a summary table per cosm_name with such columns for each brand as:

```
Name = cosm_name (DISTINCT)  

Quantity in stock = (SUM(cosm_volume) - SUM(cosmSpent_volume)) / cosm_volume
```

Current price = here I dont even know how to address the price of the currently used row. E.g. if cosmInOut table has 3 rows for needed cosm_name with cosm_volume = 100, and SUM(cosmSpent_volume) = 150, the I have to address the second row in CosmInOut table for my cosm_name for the current price. How do I do that?

So far I managed to create this query:

```
$sql = "SELECT cosmInOut_id, cosm_brand, cosm_name, cosm_volume, cosmInOut_priceIn, 
                       SUM(cosm_volume) AS cosm_volume_total,
                       SUM(cosmSpent_volume) AS cosmSpent_total
        FROM cosmInOut
        JOIN cosmetics ON cosmInOut.cosmInOut_name=cosmetics.cosm_name
        LEFT JOIN cosmSpent ON cosmInOut.cosmInOut_name=cosmSpent.cosmSpent_name
        WHERE cosmInOut_4sale = '0' AND cosm_brand = '" . $row_brand['cosm_brand']. "'
        GROUP BY cosm_name";
```

it is performed for each cosm_brand in a cycle.
Unfortunately the math is all wrong in this query due to (I think) LEFT JOIN used.

I have 2 questions:
1. How can I fix the query to count correctly
2. How can I address the N row based on count value

Your help will be greatly appreciated. I am a new to this so don't judge too strictly. If the problem is with the architecture, I am open to suggestions

As for sample data:
[image]

A little explanation of desired result:

```
Total cosmInOut_volume is 60*3 = 180,  
total cosmSpent volume = 10+55+5+10 = 80,  
thus qty in stock = (180-80)/60 = 1.66.
```

Currently, the second row is being used to determine price because we've already used one full row (60) and began to use the second

Here is MySQL: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fdfad9/1

```
    CREATE TABLE cosmetics
    (`cosm_id` int, `cosm_brand` varchar(50), `cosm_name` varchar(50), `cosm_volume` int)
;

INSERT INTO cosmetics
    (`cosm_id`, `cosm_brand`, `cosm_name`, `cosm_volume`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Londa', 'L 5/66', '60')

;

CREATE TABLE cosmInOut
    (`cosmInOut_id` int, `cosmInOut_name` varchar(50), `cosmInOut_qty` int, `cosmInOut_priceIn` float, `cosmInOut_4sale` tinyint)
;

INSERT INTO cosmInOut
    (`cosmInOut_id`, `cosmInOut_name`, `cosmInOut_qty`, `cosmInOut_priceIn`, `cosmInOut_4sale`)
VALUES
    (1, 'L 5/66', '1', '7', '0'),
    (2, 'L 5/66', '1', '10', '0'),
    (3, 'L 5/66', '1', '7', '0')

;

CREATE TABLE cosmSpent
    (`cosmSpent_id` int, `cosmSpent_name` varchar(50), `cosmSpent_volume` int)
;

INSERT INTO cosmSpent
    (`cosmSpent_id`, `cosmSpent_name`, `cosmSpent_volume`)
VALUES
    (1, 'L 5/66', '10'),
    (2, 'L 5/66', '55'),
    (3, 'L 5/66', '5'),
    (4, 'L 5/66', '10')

;
```

Comment: what is `AI` you mention three times?

Comment: To help you we need sample data and desire output.

Comment: AI is Auto Increment

Comment: cosm_name = cosmInOut_name = cosmSpent_name  

As for sample data:  
In cosmInOut I have 3 rows with the same cosmInOut_name with cosm_volume = 60 and cosmInOut_priceIn = 5 | 10 | 7 respectively  
In cosmSpent I have 4 rows:  
1. cosmSpent_volume = 10  
2. cosmSpent_volume = 55  
3. cosmSpent_volume = 5  
4. cosmSpent_volume = 10  

What I need is to get the following results:  
cosm_name;  
Quantity in stock = 1.66; 
Current price = 10

Comment: Update the question and format it properly, is very hard to read it on comment

Comment: post updated. Thanks

Comment: I try to improve the format, but couldnt do much more. Try reading this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96125/how-to-format-sql-tables-in-a-stack-overflow-post The clear and easy to read your question is the more answer you can get. Ppl doesnt have time to try decript your question. Good Luck

Comment: results from that app looks fine in edit window but not so good in preview.
Here is the printscreen: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9agne2tt82wz57d/tables.jpg?dl=0 Hope it clarifies

Comment: when you paste that text in your question.. Select and press ctrl-k. or in the toolbox there is a botton for `code`

Comment: I include your picture, but is better if you use formated text, so other can copy/paste. Now how qty is 1.66 ? and price 10 instead of 7. You should update the question and explain using the picture (or text) as reference

Comment: thanks, I will try that next time. As for qty: Total cosmInOut_volume is 60*3 = 180, total cosmSpent volume = 10+55+5+10 = 80, thus qty in stock = (180-80)/60 = 1.66. Currently, the second row is being used to determine price because we've already used one full row (60) and began to use the second

Comment: can you send me the link with text code ... i dont want type to create those tables. Or create a http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: Updated post with sqlfiddle. Great tool by the way!

Comment: Is great but sometimes is overload, so you have to post your text code here anyway. Did you ust `TEXT to DDL` function on the top to create the tables?

Comment: updated again with the code to create tables

Comment: Why Is Cosmetic in/out I only see IN.

Comment: others are relevant only if cosmInOut_4sale = 1, which is not the case now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/040db/24)**

To produce your desire result you need create three querys and join it together.

- First you need know how much volumen is for each cosmetic name, and how much items buy for those name
- Then Calculate the total spend for each name
- Using variables you calculate ranges of volumen and what price correspont to that range

.

```
SELECT v_in.*, 
       v_out.cosm_IO_vol,
       (v_in.cosm_volume * v_in.cosm_qty - v_out.cosm_IO_vol) 
           /  v_in.cosm_volume as  QtyStock,
       price.`cosmInOut_priceIn`
FROM (  SELECT C.cosm_name, 
               C.cosm_volume,
               SUM(IO.cosmInOut_qty) as cosm_qty 
        FROM cosmetics  C
        JOIN cosmInOut  IO
          ON C.`cosm_name` = IO.`cosmInOut_name`
        GROUP BY   C.cosm_name
     ) v_in
LEFT JOIN (SELECT cosmSpent_name,  SUM(cosmSpent_volume) as cosm_IO_vol
           FROM cosmSpent CS
           GROUP BY cosmSpent_name
          ) v_out
  ON v_in.`cosm_name` = v_out.`cosmSpent_name` 
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT  C.cosm_name, 
                    IF(@cosm_name = C.cosm_name, 
                       @volume,
                       0) minVolume,
                    @volume := IF(@cosm_name = C.cosm_name,
                                  @volume + C.cosm_volume * IO.cosmInOut_qty,
                                  IF(@cosm_name := C.cosm_name,
                                     C.cosm_volume,
                                     C.cosm_volume)
                                 ) as maxVolume,
                    `cosmInOut_priceIn`           
            FROM cosmetics  C
            JOIN cosmInOut  IO
              ON C.`cosm_name` = IO.`cosmInOut_name`
            CROSS JOIN (SELECT  @cosm_name := '', @volume := 0) Y
            ORDER BY C.cosm_volume, cosmInOut_id
           ) price
       ON v_in.cosm_name = price.cosm_name
      AND v_out.cosm_IO_vol BETWEEN price.minVolume AND price.maxVolume
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| cosm_name | cosm_volume | cosm_qty | cosm_IO_vol | QtyStock | cosmInOut_priceIn |
|-----------|-------------|----------|-------------|----------|-------------------|
|    L 5/66 |          60 |        3 |          80 |   1.6667 |                10 |
```

Comment: That's great! Only one stupid question: where should I input the WHERE clause? `WHERE cosmInOut_4sale = '0'`

Comment: Though it works in SQL Fiddle demo, phpmyadmin throws an exception: `#1054 - Unknown column 'IO.cosmInOut_qty' in 'field list'`. Honestly, I undestand next to nothing in this query, so I don't really know how to make it work

Comment: OK, with `Where` clause I dealt by changing `SUM` function at line 7 of your demo like so `SUM(IF(cosmInOut_4sale = 0, 
                       IO.cosmInOut_qty, 0)) as cosm_qty`. But my real database still throws that `#1054` exception. I'm using the same PHP 5.6 as the demo

Comment: You can run each subquery separated and try to see what data bring. But I cant do anything more for you the query you request was very complicated and took lot of time so you cant expect get an easy query.

Comment: OK, Thanks alot for your help. As I figure the problem is somewhere with derived tables. I will be looking into it